# UITabBarController as secondary controller in UISplitViewController is producing 2 navigation bars in compact view

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uikit, uisplitviewcontroller

This is a bit of an odd one, but when using UIKit (I've tried it in SwiftUI and the same result doesn't happen), and attempting to place a `UITabViewController` as the secondary item in a `UISplitViewController`, an extra `UINavigationBar` is presented on the secondary view controller, but only when viewed in its compact form. Selected another tab and revisiting that view fixes the problem. Here are some images - a direct screenshot and one from the view debugger:

[Image of problem on iPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxZPW.jpg)
[Image of view debugger showing two tab bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OvMt.jpg)

Here is my code, I've pulled it out of a larger project but it still is reproducible:

```
import UIKit

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        guard let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene else { return }

        let splitViewController = UISplitViewController(style: .doubleColumn)

        let primaryVc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: PrimaryTestUIViewController())
        let tabBar = UITabBarController()
        tabBar.viewControllers = [UINavigationController(rootViewController: SecondaryTestUIViewController()),
                                  UINavigationController(rootViewController: SecondaryTestUIViewController()),
                                  UINavigationController(rootViewController: SecondaryTestUIViewController())]

        let secondaryVC = tabBar

        splitViewController.viewControllers = [primaryVc, secondaryVC]

        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window.rootViewController = splitViewController
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}

class PrimaryTestUIViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = "Primary view"
    }

}

class SecondaryTestUIViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = "Secondary view"
    }

}
```